# Install Windows 8 (on secondary hard disk) on an Ubuntu machine (on primary hard disk)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, hard-drive

I have Ubuntu 13.10 installed on my primary hard disk and I was not able to install Windows in that drive. So I bought a new secondary drive. How can I install Windows 8 on my secondary drive without affecting Ubuntu, and will I be needing to update Grub? What partition table to use on the secondary drive?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is Ubuntu UEFI or BIOS installed? Also either disconnect Ubuntu drive or change Windows drive to be BIOS boot drive before installing Windows. It will force a install of a boot partition on the BIOS boot drive and if that is Ubuntu it will just overwrite the beginning of the drive.

Comment: @oldfred my Ubuntu is BIOS installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **PC without UEFI**

**Method 1**

- You can try **EasyBCD**
- **Download EasyBCD** [here](http://neosmart.net/Download/Register)  **[Just type any name or email-id and click "Download!"]**
- [See instruction using EasyBCD](https://www.maketecheasier.com/configure-the-boot-menu-windows-8/)

If your PC **have UEFI** following will work

**Method 2**

- **Intall Windows 8**
- **Download Boot-Repair Disk** [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) and burn it to any disk.
- **Boot that Disk** and click **"Recommanded Repair"**.

**OR**

**Method 3**

- Install Windows 8
- **Create Ubuntu USB Disk using iso that you have used for installation with storage**
- **Open terminal and run `sudo apt-get install boot-repair`**

launch Boot-Repair from either :

- the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
- or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
- or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
- Then click the "Recommended repair" button.

Comment: when i press "Recommended repair" there is a warning "LDM blocker detected". I don't know what to do...

Comment: @ganezdragon You can use easybcd after instaling GRUB using esybcd you can boot into ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, use whatever partition table you want to.

Because it is on second disk it won't affect Ubuntu installation or GRUB. Just make sure that you have installed GRUB (and updated its configuration) on disk with Ubuntu installed, so it can recognise Windows installation.

In your BIOS, select drive with Ubuntu to boot first and that should be it.